# Share dual monitor setup across 2 machines

Tags: mac, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, desktop-computer

I am only now realising what I wanted to do is not the norm. Through accidents of fate, I have a pc, a mac laptop and 2 monitors. Is it **technically** possible, to have a switcher that allows me to switch between machines while **maintaining a dual monitor setup in each case**(i.e. regardless of which machine I'm working on)? What would be the correct topology?

## machines:

- 1 x mac laptop
- 1 x pc tower

## monitors:

- 2 x monitors (both hdmi-capable)

## peripherals

- 1 x keyboard and mouse for the pc setup (old style usb, not the tiny new usb-c ones)
- 1 x Magic keyboard + Magic mouse for the mac (I am thinking I will not need these?)
- 1 x USB-C-to-HDMI dongle for the mac (I suspect I'll need an extra one?)

## Switchers

- 1 x [AIMOS KVM 2*1 switch](https://www.amazon.ca/AIMOS-Computers-Keyboard-Wireless-Connections/dp/B0852FGD85) (comes with 2 hdmi cables)

Any tips / advice appreciated. I suspect even if I got another mac dongle for the second monitor, only one machine will have dual monitor setup, while the other can only ever have one. Am I right? What other equipment would I need to get the desired setup? I'm worried I bought the wrong switch. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dual monitor HDMI KVM switches like [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/GREATHTEK-Dual-Monitor-HDMI-Switch/dp/B07ZYGRQGW/).  As long as your PC and Mac laptop support multiple monitors (or have expansion dongles to add displays like the ones you have for your Mac), you can hook them up with this and switch between the computers on the monitors.

Another possibility is to use separate switches for video and USB input devices (mouse and keyboard).  Here is an example of a 2 in / 2 out [HDMI Matrix switch](https://www.amazon.ca/Orei-Switcher-UltraHD-Supports-UHDS-202/dp/B08FBMKY9T/) and a [USB device sharing switch](https://www.amazon.ca/Selector-Switcher-One-Button-Swapping-Keyboard/dp/B07WPC74VG/).

The pros and cons are that separate switches are less expensive, but require you to switch 2 switches to switch both the video and the controls.  KVMs typically support hot key switching (key combo on the connected keyboard) whereas the separate switches will probably require you physically press a button on the switch itself.

Note that these are just examples, so you should shop around for the best deal in terms of price, functionality and reliability.

Comment: Thank you so much @Blaelph! As I commented on your other answer this helps me see exactly where I went wrong: basically this scales up from a standalone dual-monitor capable system. PC tower is old: only 1 hdmi out. the other is a pin connector. I should have solved for that first.

Comment: @yen, glad I could help.  I'm not sure what you mean by "pin connector".  VGA connectors have 15 pins and are analog, so they're not compatible with HDMI without an active converter, but DVI-I and DVI-D can be adapted to HDMI with a passive adapter or cable with DVI on one side and HDMI on the other.  Here's a [diagram](https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/TV/WireCableConversions/VideoConnectors.png) to illustrate what they look like.  Another option could be to upgrade your video card or use a USB to HDMI display adapter if your pc has enough memory to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility you can do with the equipment you already have is use the KVM to switch between computers on the main screen only, leaving your second screen to be directly connected to the PC.

The setup would look something like this:
video setup 
PC HDMI output 1 > KVM HDMI input 1 > 
MAC USB-C to HDMI > KVM HDMI input 2 > 
KVM HDMI output > to Monitor 1

PC HDMI out 2 > Monitor 2

mouse/keyboard setup 
USB Mouse > KVM USB input 
USB Keyboard > KVM USB input 
KVM USB output 1 > PC USB input 
KVM USB output 2 > MAC USB input

[image: setup diagram]

You could arrange your MAC laptop and second monitor to be individual secondary screens on the sides, with the KVM switched monitor 1 in the middle that stays synced with your keyboard, depending on if your desk is large enough to hold the 2 monitors and MAC laptop.  This setup would support dual monitors for each computer, but only 1 would be shared via the KVM switch.

Just thought I'd add a suggestion that uses the equipment you already have on hand.  I hope you find these suggestions useful.

Comment: Thank you so much @Blaelph! This helps me see exactly where I went wrong